# How to select value as row from period column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table for product order properties.

```
OrderId     |  SerialFrom        |  Serial To
1           |  6605181145833976  |  6605181145833980
```

How can I show it in this way:

```
SerialId
6605181145833976
6605181145833977
6605181145833978
6605181145833979
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can do that by a recursive CTE. Note that you mean `6605181145833979` in the last row instead of `6605181145833978`

Comment: Stop and think. If you include the lower boundary (...3976), why do you not **not** include the upper boundary (...3980)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive **[`CTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** as

```
CREATE TABLE Data(
  OrderId INT,
  SerialFrom BIGINT,
  SerialTo BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO Data VALUES
(1, 6605181145833976, 6605181145833980);

WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT SerialFrom
  FROM Data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SerialFrom + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE CTE.SerialFrom < 6605181145833979
)
SELECT SerialFrom SerialId
FROM CTE;
```

**Returns:**

```
+------------------+
|     SerialId     |
+------------------+
| 6605181145833976 |
| 6605181145833977 |
| 6605181145833978 |
| 6605181145833979 |
+------------------+
```

Since the number of rows is known, and it's only 4 values, you can use also **[`Table Value Constructor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** (which is the best choice in this case) as

```
SELECT SerialFrom + Number SerialId
FROM Data D CROSS JOIN 
     (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3)) T(Number);
```

You can also do the same with `master..spt_values` system table as

```
SELECT SerialFrom + Number SerialId
FROM Data D CROSS JOIN 
     master..spt_values T
WHERE T.[Type] = 'P'
      AND
      [Number] <= 3;
```

Althought, I recommend to not use `master..spt_values` system table as it's not documented, and  undocumented system tables can be changed by Microsoft without warning, so you should avoid using them. Still it's your choice :).

Finally, here is a **[`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=08b715a798fe87a923060de6b6d9d71e)** to play with and see how it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Tally table of numbers will help. It can be a predefined table or created on the fly as in the query below.

```
with L0(N) as (
    select top(10) null from sys.all_objects
),L1(N) as (--  10**2
    select null 
    from L0 a1
    cross join L0 a2
),L2(N) as (--  10**2**2
    select null 
    from L1 a1
    cross join L1 a2
), tally as(
        select n = row_number() over(order by N) - 1
        from L2
)
select OrderId, SerialFrom + n 
from Mytable mt
join tally t on t.n <= SerialTo - SerialFrom
```